# Infer type arguments and hold a generic type instance in Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to fill a gap in my knowledge of generics in Java.
Consider the following java class that is supposed to hold an instance of an ArchiveOutputStream. The example is simplified from the real world example I'm working on but it shows the problem.

Why cant the compiler infer type arguments for ArchiveStreamHolder<>?

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream;

public class ArchiveStreamHolder<T extends ArchiveOutputStream<E>, E extends ArchiveEntry> {
    final T archiveStream;

    private ArchiveStreamHolder(T archiveStream) {
        this.archiveStream = archiveStream;
    }
    
    public static <T extends ArchiveOutputStream<E>, E extends ArchiveEntry> ArchiveStreamHolder<T,E> of(OutputStream os, boolean zip) {
      if (zip) {
        return new ArchiveStreamHolder<>(new ZipArchiveOutputStream(os));
      }
      else {
        return new ArchiveStreamHolder<>(new TarArchiveOutputStream(os));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which concrete type(s) do you expect it to infer? Can you infer it manually? Why do you need `E` as a separate type parameter?

Comment: @komen this.. isn't what generics are for at all. Generics are compile-time only constructs. What you're attempting to do here is a runtime thing, which just doesn't work and cannot 'just' be fixed. Mostly the generics have no place here - your `of` method returns either an A or a B and the compiler couldn't possibly infer which one of the two things you get. Which means generics do not work here, and this method should just return an `ArchiveStreamHolder<?, ?>`, ditch T and E.